# Unable to design the responsive multipicker using jQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have developed a multipicker control using jQuery and CSS. The functionality of the control is working properly, but it is not responisive because we are varying the size of the `ul` by applying margins.

How can I make it responsive for multipicker?

Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LAQwCzqjoPpmxdZyO0Vq?p=preview).

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: As far as I can see, within your plunker, the multipicker is responsive. Do you want to have a specific lay-out when you downscale the window?

Comment: hi @Rotan075, It is responsive but we need to increase size of the ul for only 3 list items without using any css.When am increasing the size of the ul by applying margins its not responsive so please help me.

Comment: do you need equal size for all your pickers?

Comment: Something like : https://plnkr.co/edit/qRR3vVjZFqYKyouuJObs?p=preview ??

Comment: hi @HimanshuTyagi, I am getting the same output but  we need to align li's with equal margins within this same length like ur plunker.